# Django: Set E-Mail settings in view

Tags: python, django, configuration, django-views, django-email

I am trying to send a email using SMTP from Google. I already get to send a email putting the setting variables in the file "settings.py" but I need to configure these variables in a view and set them using my "Config" model.

This is my model code:

```
class Config(models.Model):
    email_sender    = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', blank = True)
    email_password  = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = '', blank = True)
    smtp_server     = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', blank = True)
    smtp_port       = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 587, blank = True)
```

This is my view code:

```
def send_custom_mail(request):
    config = Config.objects.get(pk = 1)
    EMAIL_HOST = config.smtp_server
    EMAIL_PORT = config.smtp_port
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = config.email_sender
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config.email_password
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    subject = 'test'
    msg = '<p>Test: <strong>Mensaje</strong>></p>'
    mail_from = config.email_sender
    mail_to = ['{}'.format(email)]
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    email2send  = EmailMessage(subject, msg, mail_from, to=mail_to)
    email2send.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
    email2send.send()
```

**My problem:** The email is not sent when I set the variables in the view.

I need to configure these variables dinamically so I can't  write it in the setting.py file.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand how you're code's set out there. Are you trying to set Django config variables (e.g. ``EMAIL_HOST``) from within the view? If so, what you've got won't work because you're just setting variables in the local scope, not modifying the Django settings. Is your question about how to modify settings values from within a view?

Comment: @RodManning yeah, that's what I want to do. I want to set the those variables from within the view to make them dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled about having to override settings in a view; never seen a use case for it before.

Strategy I'd normally use would be to fall-back either to lower-level functions.

I'd suggest that you could achieve what you seem to need to by using the `send_mail()` function and `get_connection()`.

Haven't tested this code, but think it would look like this:

```
from django.core import mail

connection = mail.get_connection(
    host = config.smtp_server,
    port = config.smtp_port,
    username = config.email_sender,
    password = config.email_password ,
    (... etc etc ...)
)

# Manually open the connection
connection.open()

# Send the message
subject = 'test'
msg = 'Test:Mensaje'
mail_to = ['test@test.com']
email2send  = EmailMessage(
    subject, 
    msg, t
    o=mail_to
    connection=connection
)

# Send the email using the custom connection
email2send.send()

# Close the connection
connection.close()
```

(Note the `connection=connection` when the EmailMessage is first setup to send the email via the custom connection.)

Django [Email Backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#email-backends) docs explain this pretty well, and this seems a more straight-forward way to do it than overriding settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, but I don't know if it is the best way to aproach this problem:

using this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/test/utils/#override_settings

In my view I overrride the setting variables:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(EMAIL_HOST = Config.objects.get(pk = 1).smtp_server)
@override_settings(EMAIL_HOST_USER = Config.objects.get(pk = 1).email_sender)
@override_settings(EMAIL_PORT = Config.objects.get(pk = 1).smtp_port)
def send_custom_mail(request):
subject = 'test'
    msg = 'Test:Mensaje'
    mail_to = ['test@test.com']
    email2send  = EmailMessage(subject, msg, to=mail_to)
    email2send.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
    email2send.send()
```

in this aproach I use "django.test.utils" to put the decorator "@override_settings()" before the "send_custom_mail" function. It override the setting and let me send emails from a mail saved in a model called Config.

Actually, I'm not sure if it is the best aproach because the "django.test" module is meant to use in unit tests, but I wanted to share my solution.

Comment: If any else can answer the correct way to approach this, I will be glad to give the correct answer to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

```
def email_sending(mail_subject, message,to, mail_obj=None):
if not mail_obj:
    try:

        mail_obj = AdminEMailsModel.objects.filter(default_email=True)[0]

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        try:
            if not mail_obj:
                mail_obj= AdminEMailsModel.objects.all()[0]

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
backend = EmailBackend(host=mail_obj.host_address, port=mail_obj.port_no, username=mail_obj.email,
                       password=mail_obj.password, use_tls=mail_obj.use_tls, fail_silently=False)
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    mail_subject, message, from_email=mail_obj.email, to=to, connection=backend
)

email.attach_alternative(message, 'text/html')
email.send()

return
```

> directly you can call this function whenever you need to send an email to register email
>   if this code is usefull to you please give up vote